# Restrict values of object to scalars

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm using Formik which has this type in it:

```
type FormikErrors<Values> = {
 [K in keyof Values]?: Values[K] extends object
  ? FormikErrors<Values[K]>
  : string
};
```

Then there's a validation function that basically looks like `validate<Values>(v: Values) => FormikErrors<Values>`. The idea is that the keys of FormikErrors match up with the keys of Values, and map to a string error message, OR a recursive FormikErrors object if that field is represented by a nested object.

I'm trying to write a generic function to validate required fields. It only needs to work with flat Values.

```
export function validateRequired<T, K extends keyof T>(values : T, names: K[]) : FormikErrors<T> {
 let errors : FormikErrors<T> = {};
 names.forEach((name) => {
  if (!values[name]) {
   errors[name] = 'This field is required';
  }
 });
 return errors;
}
```

This is an error though:

```
Type error: Type '"This field is required"' is not assignable to type '(T[K] extends object ? FormikErrors<T[K]> : string) | undefined'. TS2322
```

Because the values of the object returned by validateRequired are always strings, never nested FormikValues. Is there a way to specify that the values will always be scalars so that this can type check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution would be not to use the `FormikErrors` type. Use a custom type that can have only string values:

```
type RequiredErrors<Values> = {
    [K in keyof Values]?: string
};

export function validateRequired<T, K extends keyof T>(values: T, names: K[]): RequiredErrors<T> {
    let errors: RequiredErrors<T> = {};
    names.forEach((name) => {
        if (!values[name]) {
            errors[name] = 'This field is required';
        }
    });
    return errors;
}
```

If this is not an option for you, then the only solution is a type assertion. Typescript can't resolve conditional types that still have unresolved generic type parameters in them and thus can't really tell if `string` is a valid value for the `errors` object, but a type assertion will fix this:

```
export function validateRequired<T, K extends keyof T>(values: T, names: K[]): FormikErrors<T> {
    let errors: FormikErrors<T> = {};
    names.forEach((name) => {
        if (!values[name]) {
            errors[name] = 'This field is required' as any;;
        }
    });
    return errors;
}
```

Comment: I thought I had to use FormikErrors (it's from a library), but it does actually work to make validateRequired return a RequiredErrors, and then the actual validate function isn't generic so it all works out.